# MPMoviePlayerController preload progress

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way of getting the preload progress of a MPMoviePlayerController?

At the moment I'm listening to for `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` and showing a UIActivityView until the `loadState` is `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable ||  MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK`.

However this can take a few seconds so I'd like to show a UIProgressView instead, so that the end user can I get an idea of how long they have to wait before the video will start.

Is this possible without using private calls (the app will be submitted to the app store)?

Comment: Good question but AFAIK that is not possible. Technically, however, that should be doable as the preloading is devided into multiple steps - whereas the final one (actual prebuffering) takes most of that total time.

Comment: The docs say nothing about such a feature, so you have by default 2 choices: using some private stuff or finding a creative workaround/fake.

Comment: I think that's a workaround... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103038/mpmovieplayercontroller-manual-loading-screen

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available. If you feel that it should be then please file a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com. Apple keeps track of what people request and if there is sufficient interest they will add this.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to iOS 5.x I used to be able to show a progress bar that indicates how much of the stream is buffered using the playableDuration property.  However, this doesn't seem to work after iOS5.x.