# MPMoviePlayerController Manual loading screen

Tags: iphone

In MPMoviewPlayerController i have to play movie from a particular url.Its work fine.I want to show a loadingview (like a spinning wheel rotate in the center of the screen with text loading please wait) before it starts playing movie. (I am using ios4.2)

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.
          when u alloc MPMoviePlayerController after that use this method.

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self      selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)   name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
  [activity startanimating];
```

and  after that use the delegate method..

```
  -(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
 {
   moviePlayer=[aNotification object];
CFShow([aNotification userInfo]);
[activity hide];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self         name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];

  }
```